# Wpf Multibinding in a template or style

Tags: wpf, xaml, multibinding, wpf-style

I have a class with many properties (not in a list) which must be switchable in view. The converter itself works fine using multibinding.

```
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IntValueConvertor}">
                        <Binding Path="property1" />
                        <Binding Path="IntegerDisplay" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
```

In the code, "IntegerDisplay" is a property which is defined in my VM.
Property1 is one of the many properties which must be viewed differently (depending on IntegerDisplay).

What I want to avoid is the need of adding the whole multibinding  convertor to each textbox.

Something in this style:

```
            <TextBox
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="4"                    
                Text="{Binding Path=Property1, Converter={StaticResource IntValueConvertor}}" />
```

I know this code does not work!

I tried using a style, but I could not get to the value of property1.
Is it the best way to use a style or is a datatemplate better?

Kind regards

Comment: Use Data Templates...

Comment: Hi, Can you explain it with some code please ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sticking with a style and here's a basic start to doing so.

```
<!--This will go in your resources-->
<Style x:Name="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Property1, Converter={StaticResource IntValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=IntegerDisplay}"/>
</Style>

<!--This will go in your Display-->
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
```